# How to initialize StrongSORT

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, object-tracking

I am trying to write a code that performs object tracking (detection and tracking). I first find the detections using Yolov5 but the problem comes when I try to initialize the StrongSort to do the tracking. My code is inspired by this [repository](https://github.com/kadirnar/yolov5-strongsort) (I have all the requirements installed) and when initializing the StrongSort, the code uses as model weights "osnet_x0_25_market1501.pt", but when I do the same I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'`

I don't know if I should input it in another way or download it from somewhere.

The code I wrote goes like is:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import cv2
from strongsort.strong_sort import StrongSORT
import os

# Load the YOLOv5 model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', pretrained=True)

# Load the StrongSORT model
tracker =   StrongSORT( model_weights= "osnet_x0_25_market1501.pt" ,
                device='cuda', fp16 = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Discalimer. I am the creator of:
> https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/yolov8_tracking

That repo is highly based on: https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/yolov8_tracking. I recommend you to use the original one.

Anyways, if you still want to use that one you could try:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import cv2
from pathlib import Path
from strongsort.strong_sort import StrongSORT
import os

# Load the YOLOv5 model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', pretrained=True)

# Load the StrongSORT model
tracker =   StrongSORT( model_weights= Path("osnet_x0_25_market1501.pt") ,
                device='cuda', fp16 = True)
```